# Adding created case statement columns together

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to add 5 columns that I have created using case statements in a select statement. Here is the detail part of the select that isn't working. My inner join of table A and table B works just fine. In a nutshell, I'm assigning values to these 5 case statement blocks and am trying to display the sum of these columns without success.

Thanks in advance...

```
[AML] = CASE
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 1 THEN 30
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 2 THEN 9
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 3 THEN 0
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 4 THEN -6
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 5 THEN -9
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 6 THEN -12
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 7 THEN -13
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 8 THEN -13
    ELSE -16
END,

[MLO] = CASE
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 1 THEN 30
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 2 THEN 11
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 3 THEN 1
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 4 THEN -6
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 5 THEN -9
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 6 THEN -11
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 7 THEN -13
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 8 THEN -14
    ELSE -15
END,

[SYS1] = CASE
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 1 THEN 29
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 2 THEN 12
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 3 THEN 0
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 4 THEN -5
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 5 THEN -9
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 6 THEN -12
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 7 THEN -13
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 8 THEN -13
    ELSE -14
END,

[K] = CASE
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 1 THEN 28
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 2 THEN 12
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 3 THEN 2
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 4 THEN -4
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 5 THEN -8
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 6 THEN -11
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 7 THEN -13
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 8 THEN -13
    ELSE -14
END,

[HTR] = CASE
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 1 THEN 27
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 2 THEN 10
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 3 THEN 0
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 4 THEN -3
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 5 THEN -9
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 6 THEN -11
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 7 THEN -11
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 8 THEN -12
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 9 THEN -14
    ELSE -15
END,

--([AML] + [MLO] + [SYS1] + [K] + [HTR]) AS [TOT], (doesn't work)
```

The bottom line of the query above is commented out because it doesn't work. The select statement displays all 5 of the newly created columns along with their proper values.

Comment: Use derived table (or cte) for the case expressions. Then sum.

Comment: It would be cleaner and safer to join tables that map the values instead of using CASE. You can use a [table value constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#c-specifying-multiple-values-as-a-derived-table-in-a-from-clause) to create "virtual" tables in the query itself

Comment: You can't access aliased column values in the select part of the query, so you have to either do as subquery or a cross apply (which i prefer) that contains the alias. An example is: `select ([AML] + [MLO] + [SYS1] + [K] + [HTR]) AS [TOT] from yourtable cross apply (select [AML] = case when ... END, SYS1 = case when ... END)  ca`

Comment: Case is an *expression* not a statement.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need those 5 colomn of yours or is it just for the sum?

If for the 5 cols use:

```
SELECT AML, ML0, SYS1, K, HTR, AML+ML0+SYS1+K+HTR AS TOT
FROM (

    SELECT
    [AML] = CASE
        WHEN [B].[rAML] = 1 THEN 30
        WHEN [B].[rAML] = 2 THEN 9
        WHEN [B].[rAML] = 3 THEN 0
        WHEN [B].[rAML] = 4 THEN -6
        WHEN [B].[rAML] = 5 THEN -9
        WHEN [B].[rAML] = 6 THEN -12
        WHEN [B].[rAML] = 7 THEN -13
        WHEN [B].[rAML] = 8 THEN -13
        ELSE -16
    END,
    
    [MLO] = CASE
        WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 1 THEN 30
        WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 2 THEN 11
        WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 3 THEN 1
        WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 4 THEN -6
        WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 5 THEN -9
        WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 6 THEN -11
        WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 7 THEN -13
        WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 8 THEN -14
        ELSE -15
    END,
    
    [SYS1] = CASE
        WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 1 THEN 29
        WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 2 THEN 12
        WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 3 THEN 0
        WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 4 THEN -5
        WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 5 THEN -9
        WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 6 THEN -12
        WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 7 THEN -13
        WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 8 THEN -13
        ELSE -14
    END,
    
    [K] = CASE
        WHEN [A].[rK] = 1 THEN 28
        WHEN [A].[rK] = 2 THEN 12
        WHEN [A].[rK] = 3 THEN 2
        WHEN [A].[rK] = 4 THEN -4
        WHEN [A].[rK] = 5 THEN -8
        WHEN [A].[rK] = 6 THEN -11
        WHEN [A].[rK] = 7 THEN -13
        WHEN [A].[rK] = 8 THEN -13
        ELSE -14
    END,
    
    [HTR] = CASE
        WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 1 THEN 27
        WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 2 THEN 10
        WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 3 THEN 0
        WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 4 THEN -3
        WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 5 THEN -9
        WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 6 THEN -11
        WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 7 THEN -11
        WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 8 THEN -12
        WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 9 THEN -14
        ELSE -15
    END) AS T
```

If for the sum then use

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 1 THEN 30
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 2 THEN 9
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 3 THEN 0
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 4 THEN -6
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 5 THEN -9
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 6 THEN -12
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 7 THEN -13
    WHEN [B].[rAML] = 8 THEN -13
    ELSE -16
END
+
CASE
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 1 THEN 30
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 2 THEN 11
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 3 THEN 1
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 4 THEN -6
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 5 THEN -9
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 6 THEN -11
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 7 THEN -13
    WHEN [A].[rMLO] = 8 THEN -14
    ELSE -15
END
+
CASE
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 1 THEN 29
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 2 THEN 12
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 3 THEN 0
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 4 THEN -5
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 5 THEN -9
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 6 THEN -12
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 7 THEN -13
    WHEN [B].[rSYS1] = 8 THEN -13
    ELSE -14
END
+
CASE
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 1 THEN 28
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 2 THEN 12
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 3 THEN 2
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 4 THEN -4
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 5 THEN -8
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 6 THEN -11
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 7 THEN -13
    WHEN [A].[rK] = 8 THEN -13
    ELSE -14
END
+
CASE
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 1 THEN 27
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 2 THEN 10
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 3 THEN 0
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 4 THEN -3
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 5 THEN -9
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 6 THEN -11
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 7 THEN -11
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 8 THEN -12
    WHEN [A].[rHTR] = 9 THEN -14
    ELSE -15
END AS [TOT]
```